# Кодировка (javascript, servlet)

Tags: javascript, servlet, unicode

Функция отправляет переменную на сервлет.

```
function callServlet(){
    alert(word);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word="+word);
    request.open("get", url, true);
    request.send();
}
```

Сервлет принимает эту переменную:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String result = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("word"), "UTF-8");
    System.out.print(result);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("src/kpfu/files.txt"));

    if (scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern,0)!=null)
        System.out.print("yes");
    else System.out.print("no");


}
```

Проблема такая: английский принимает, русский нет. Что делать - не представляю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

```
public Scanner(InputStream source,
       String charsetName)
```

> **charsetName** - The encoding type used to convert bytes from the stream
>   into characters to be scanned

Попробуйте задать кодировку:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("src/kpfu/files.txt"),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Со сканером у меня проблем нет, там все ок. Проблема у меня с сервлетом и джаваскриптом. Конкретнее, в строчках: var url = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word="+word); /  String result = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("word"), "UTF-8");
    System.out.print(result);

Comment: Попробуйте так:

var url = "http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word=" + escape(encodeURIComponent(word))

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Мне помогло. Очень вам благодарна!

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос я нашел [тут](http://xhtml.ru/2006/05/25/encodestring/) в комментариях. Почитайте и их и саму статью, очень информативно.